# Remove default styles from draggable content inside of contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I am trying to create simple WYSIWYG editor and I have faced with following problem.
When user copies or drag text inside of `contenteditable` div. 
According to information from the Google I have added following code for copy/paste:

```
var $mainInput = $('#main-input');
$mainInput.on('paste', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
    lastCaretIndex.insertNode(document.createTextNode(text));
});
```

And it works like a charm:

[image]

But with drag&drop it doesn't work as expected.
I found similar posts on Stackoverflow:

1) [This one uses jQuery UI which is irrelevant for my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273461/how-can-i-clear-the-styles-on-a-draggable-elements-children-before-moving-the)

2) [Event described here doesn't provide ability to customize draggable text, only target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280738/drag-and-drop-event-in-a-contenteditable-element)

And some others pieces, so I got following code:

```
$mainInput.on('dragend', function(e) {
 window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(document.createTextNode(strip(t)));
});
```

And the result:

[image]

Also, I tried to do this according to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#drop), but this fully removes old element content.
Code:

```
$mainInput.bind('drop', function (e) {
    event.target.textContent = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Example:

[image]

Can somebody please help me, or give some advice how this could be handled.

Current state is available in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t3au601k/)

================= PS ===============
This is solved. Version which works for most browsers - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sj6qzb2t/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the text is dropped, the `span` at the drop point is split in two and a new `span` is inserted in between. I haven't seen an option of the drag-and-drop to prevent that behavior. One way to avoid it is to replace the default transfer mechanism.

In the `drop` event handler, you can move the text manually if you find that it will end up in a different `span`. The destination range can be found with [`createCollapsedRangeFromPoint`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28275304/1009922), a function provided by [Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96100/tim-down). The range can then be compared with the original selection range.

The following code can be tested in [**this jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ConnorsFan/tdk1o5g7/18/). It works in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE11. The default drag-and-drop behavior is used when the customized one is not supported.

```
var $mainInput = $('#main-input');
var draggedText;
var dragStartContainer;
var dragEndContainer;
var dragStartOffset;
var dragEndOffset;

$mainInput.on('dragstart', function(e) {
    var dragRange = getSelectionRange();
    dragStartContainer = dragRange.startContainer;
    dragEndContainer = dragRange.endContainer;
    dragStartOffset = dragRange.startOffset;
    dragEndOffset = dragRange.endOffset;
    draggedText = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text");
});

$mainInput.on('drop', function(e) {
    // Get caret at mouse cursor position
    var range = createCollapsedRangeFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    var container = range.startContainer;
    // If text is moved to another container, do it manually
    if (container && (container !== dragStartContainer || container !== dragEndContainer)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Insert dragged text at caret position
        var startOffset = range.startOffset;
        var str = container.textContent;
        var strPrepend = str.substr(0, range.startOffset);
        var strAppend = str.substr(range.startOffset);
        container.textContent = strPrepend + draggedText + strAppend;
        // Delete text at original position
        var spaceCount = getSpaceCountAtStart(container);
        setSelectionRange(dragStartContainer, dragEndContainer, dragStartOffset, dragEndOffset);
        document.execCommand("delete", false);
        var spaceCountCorrection = getSpaceCountAtStart(container) - spaceCount;
        // Select text at new position
        var startRemoved = (dragEndContainer === container ? dragEndOffset - 1 : 0);
        var startOffset = Math.max(0, startOffset + spaceCountCorrection - startRemoved);
        var endOffset = startOffset + draggedText.length;
        setSelectionRange(container, container, startOffset, endOffset);
    }
});

// Get the number of spaces at start of container
// After moving text, that number may change
// and screw up range position calculations
function getSpaceCountAtStart(container) {
    var innerHTML = container.parentNode.innerHTML;
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < innerHTML.length; i++) {
        if (innerHTML[i] === ' ') {
            count += 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

// Function provided by Tim Down at https://stackoverflow.com/a/28275304/1009922
function createCollapsedRangeFromPoint(x, y) {
    var doc = document;
    var position, range = null;
    if (typeof doc.caretPositionFromPoint != "undefined") {
        position = doc.caretPositionFromPoint(x, y);
        range = doc.createRange();
        range.setStart(position.offsetNode, position.offset);
        range.collapse(true);
    } else if (typeof doc.caretRangeFromPoint != "undefined") {
        range = doc.caretRangeFromPoint(x, y);
    } else if (typeof doc.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        range = doc.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToPoint(x, y);
    }
    return range;
}

function getSelectionRange() {
    var sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            return sel.getRangeAt(0);
        }
    } else if (document.selection) {
        return document.createRange();
    }
    return null;
}

function setSelectionRange(startContainer, endContainer, startOffset, endOffset) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(startContainer, startOffset);
    range.setEnd(endContainer, endOffset);
    sel.addRange(range);
}
```